# How to load JSON files to swift playgrounds?

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I want to load JSON file to swift playground in two type, but it seems a bit confusing because after adding the astronaout.json file (in the first line) it gives the error "top level statement cannot begin with a closure expression", I don't know how to fix it, 2.error is missions. json file (on line 3) 'consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ";".

Any idea how to fix that?

[missions.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27EvJ.png)*

I can’t show the whole code of this files cuz it’s 369 line*

[Astronaut.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1QXB.png)*

And here is the bundle-decodable code;

```
import Foundation

extension Bundle {
  func decode(_ file: String) -> [String:    Astronaut] {
      guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
        fatalError("failed to locate \(file) in bundle")
     }
      
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf:   url) else {
          fatalError("failed to load \(file) from bundle")
    }
    
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    guard let loaded = try?  decoder.decode([String: Astronaut].self, from: data) else {
        fatalError("failed to decode \(file)     from bundle")
    }
     return loaded
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to add your json files as resources and not source code files to the playground.

- Go to the Project Navigator (Cmd-1)
- Click on the top folder to expand it if it's not already expanded
- Select the "Resources" folder and choose *File->Add Files to "Resources"...* (Opt-Cmd-A) and then select the file(s)

In the playground you access the files using the `Bundle` class, there are several ways, one is

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "missions", withExtension: "json"), 
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
    // decode data object
}
```

Comment: That error suggests you're not in a playground.